# What does Alucard's hand symbol mean?

Tags: hellsing

I was wondering what could Alucard's hand symbol mean.

[image]

I spent the whole day searching for it, but nothing. I need full information about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [image]
>
> This fictional pentagram is the seal of the Hellsing family, an anime cartoon (manga) series. The pentagram on the back of Alucard's (a hellsing character) glove is inscribed: "Hellsing - Hell's Gate arrested - Gott Mit Uns (God With Us) - And shine heaven now." The runes are written in the Trithemian alphabet, and the other symbols are a combination of Japanese, Kanji (or, Chinese), and alchemist symbols.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gott_mit_uns&oldid=911169823)

Two of the five symbols in the center are alchemist symbols. I`m able to recognize symbols for Uranus and Neptune (Neptunus). The other symbols come from the Japanese (katakana, hiragana, or kanji), or the Chinese alphabet, but the meaning of those symbols exceeds my knowledge, and maybe they are modified to some extent.

> I can`t say with 100% accuracy, but since Uranus and Neptune represent the symbols for Sky/Air (Uranus, God of Sky) and Water (Neptune, God of Water) the other represent other elements (fire, earth, metal), bottom one highly resembles Japanese kanji symbol for fire.

---

Translated runes from Thebean script (alphabet), after some corrections should go like this:

> [image: Translation]

Comment: Thinking over the canon and how Alucard is bound to protect the head of the hellsing family; I would not take this binding seal being to the organization but the family itself.

Answer (score 1):

You got 2 pentagrams in the center, symbolising most probably his duality, since he is evil but hunts evil beings.

Near the triangles, you see 5 symbols, which represent in one way or another the pentagram. The "PSI" sign can be linked to the spirit, psychē (meaning “breath, the principle of life, life, soul,”. As a deduction, the rest are also symbols of the elements.

In the inner circle, you see Hellsing, the name of the organisation, and since he is part of it, it has blesses and values "Gott mitt uns" (God with us), and "Shine heaven now" (their "value").

Outer circles are some runes I have no idea about, and below, it is 812, which I think it's the Gematria code, in which 812 can be calculated from: (commit to the antichrist, I am archangel Azrael, satanist pastor, narcissistic beasts, etc.)

Above the number, it can be the layers of the organisation. In old times, they had to stack signs to explain a person's worth (we still have them in police or military).

Everything is just a personal opinion and might be false. Take it with a grain of salt :)

Answer (score 0):

So, most of what everyone here is saying is more or less accurate.

One layer of complexity I’ve found regarding this symbol is how closely it resembles the seals of Goetia from the lesser key of Solomon; dark age alchemical efforts to conjure and bind demons to serve.

This ties pretty closely with Alucard's backstory and in the OVA. There’s a flashback in the OVA where the seal of Solomon is literally seen sitting on Papa Hellsing’s desk also, which lends a lot of credence to the theory that Alucard was bound to the service of the family through the use of Goetia.

All told, it’s a pretty funky little bit of history to bring up at parties.

Answer (score 0):

If you add up the numbers on the glove, it is 832, which is an angel number, love, twin flame, and many other meanings.

Comment: I agree with Ben If you ad up The lines with the number 812 you get the number 32 which has many different meanings

Comment: Well 832 Which has many meanings. including the angel number

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. While we appreciate anyone's contribution, note that pure opinion/speculative answer is discouraged. Instead, consider [edit]ing and trying to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.